# C# Slow Regex Performance

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex. How to optimize this regex:

```
private static readonly Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(.*)</([a-z]+)>([0-9.]+)<(.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I used it on a recursive function:

```
    private static string ReplaceMe(string temp)
    {
        if (rgx.IsMatch(temp))
        {
            temp = rgx.Replace(temp, delegate(Match m)
            {
                return m.Groups[1].Value + "</" + m.Groups[2].Value + "><span style=\"display:inline\">" + m.Groups[3].Value + "</span><" + m.Groups[4].Value;
            });

            return ReplaceMe(temp);
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

the profiler said that the statement:

```
if (rgx.IsMatch(temp))
```

is causing the performance issue, so I need to optimize the regex.

EDIT: I ended up using regex

```
([^<]*)</([a-z]+)>([0-9.]+)<(.*)
```

Comment: What you want to do using Regular expression?

Comment: What specifically are your problems with that regex? Please edit your post to add that info.

Comment: One question, why do you you write a dot after the 0-9? The dot represents ANY character (except new line), so... the block ([0-9.]+) is equivalent to (.+) ...

Comment: You'll need to define "slow" and how you're using it. On it's own, there's nothing wrong with that regex.

Comment: @castarco: No. The dot matches a literal dot. It's inside a character class.

Comment: The regex looks fine to me. Did a profiler tell  you it's really a performance problem?

Comment: edited. sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp somewhat prone to catastrophic backtracking.  Because `(.*)` can overlap with `</([a-z]+)`.  This can create problems if you are searching text where you do not find the match, and there are a lot of tags, and thus a lot of places where the second group could start.

However, until you give us an indication of how you intend to use the regexp there is little we can do to help.

You might want to consider

```
</([a-z]+)>([0-9.]+)<
```

Or

```
([^<]*)</([a-z]+)>([0-9.]+)<(.*)
```

Or you might want to use an xml parser.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases it is not really performant if you're using **RegexOptions.Compiled**.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969158/when-not-to-use-regexoptions-compiled).

Try removing **RegexOptions.Compiled** and see if it's better.

Comment: I couldn't see any performance gain from eliminating RegexOptions.Compiled

Comment: Can you give a citation or example?  If you're excluding the construction cost of the RegEx object, I was pretty sure that Compiled was never worse.