# Thread Contention Using Regex.Matches inside Parallel.ForEach Loop

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I'm encountering a lot of thread contention when using Regex.Matches inside a Parallel.ForEach loop. My understanding is that the static Regex class is thread safe, but that the returned match collections are not ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/thread-safety-in-regular-expressions)). In this implementation I think that returned collected 'matches' is only being used inside the single thread it was created in. My understanding of how static classes are impacted by parallelism isn't great though, so I would appreciate the help!

> The Regex class itself is thread safe and immutable (read-only). That is, Regex >objects can be created on any thread and shared between threads; matching >methods can be called from any thread and never alter any global state.
>
> However, result objects (Match and MatchCollection) returned by Regex should be >used on a single thread ..

```
public ConcurrentBag<string> parseFile(string txtFile, List<string> regexPatterns)
{
    ConcurrentBag<string> matchBag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(txtFile))
    {
        //loop through lines in parallel
        Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(txtFile), (line) =>
        {
            //loop through search patterns
            foreach (string pattern in regexPatterns)
            {
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //LOTS OF CONTENTION HERE

                foreach (var match in matches)
                {
                    matchBag.Add(match.ToString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return matchBag;
}
```

I've also included a screenshot of the profiler results, so you can see specifically where the contention is occurring. 
[Contention Profiler Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekMzc.png)

Comment: `In this implementation I think that returned collected 'matches' is only being used inside the single thread it was created in.` You are correct.

Comment: The issue is likely nothing to do with parallelism. It is more likely you have a poor Regex. Please update your post to include a sample text file (maybe a few lines) and a sample `regexPatterns` (all of them preferably).

Comment: You may also wish to consider compiling the regexes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969158/when-not-to-use-regexoptions-compiled) - your current code may be inefficient because you run the regexes multiple times (i.e for every line in the file).

Comment: Are you sure issues are due to regex and not from the locking that ConcurrentBag does internally?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I'm not certain - I've added a screenshot of the profiler results if that helps discern the cause. I'm interested to hear more about how the internal locking from ConcurrentBag may have an impact though

Comment: I second the compiled regex. You may want to consider passing a `List<Regex>` into the method where all of them use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag. Depending on whether these regex are static (unchanging) you may also look into compiling them to an assembly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ek5zak6(v=vs.110).aspx The Static methods of the regex class are supposed to be optimized/cached/similar for something like the last ten patterns used (no citation, sorry). Depending on how many patterns you use, a Regex object may be more appropriate

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 For clarification - do you mean that the Regex class interpreting the pattern / using it from the cache (I have set the cache limit much higher than 10 elsewhere) would cause a thread contention OR noting that in general using compiled regex is faster?

Comment: Well my point is that you are using a concurrent collection. In order for a concurrent collection to work, it has to maintain a method of synchronization (something like `lock()`) to guarantee concurrent readers and writers can work together. In other words all threads most likely cannot Add at once, they have to wait their turn. Though I admit I don't know the internals of this collection specifically, I imagine that there is some sort of synchronization going on (or what point would it serve)

Comment: When compared to no other options, `RegexOptions.Compiled` is faster. Compiled to assembly is even faster than that. However creating an instance of the former takes longer (so not worth it for single or small usages), the latter requires you build a separate dll (so can't be done 'on the fly'). There are pros and cons to each method. My point about the Caching (or whatever it is) was in regards to the **static** methods of the `Regex` class (`Regex.Matches(...)`) and not of a `Regex` object (`new Regex(...).Matches(...)`)

Comment: It would be interesting to test the speed of using `Parallel.For` compare to just a normal loop as Regex is fast and doing this in parallel might actually be much slower.