# How to replace list of strings in text with items from another list?

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

Suppose I have a list of strings {"boy", "car", "ball"} and a text "the boy sold his car to buy a ball".

Given another string list {"dog", "bar", "bone"}, my objective is to find all occurrences of the first list inside the text and swap them for the strings of the second list:

```
BEFORE: the [boy] sold his [car] to buy a [ball]
AFTER:  the [dog] sold his [bar] to buy a [bone]
```

My first thought was to use Regex but I have no idea how to associate a list of strings into a regex and I don't want to write Aho-Corasick.

What is the right way to go for that?

---

Another example:

```
Text: aaa bbb abab aabb bbaa ubab
replacing {aa, bb, ab, ub} for {11, 22, 35, &x}

BEFORE: [aa]a [bb]b [ab][ab] [aa][bb] [bb][aa] [ub][ab]
AFTER:  [11]a [22]b [35][35] [11][22] [22][11] [&x][35]
```

Comment: Can you simply replace the first target string, then the second one, and then the third one? Are you optimizing for performance? If so, how many strings do you receive and how long they can be?

Comment: I'd like to go for an O(n) approach. The example above is quite simple, but the text can be large and the list of strings too, and they may repeat a lot.

Comment: If so, I think (but am uncertain) a suffix tree can do this in O(n) where n is the total length of all strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use regex, you may use something like this:

```
var findList = new List<string>() { "boy", "car", "ball" };
var replaceList = new List<string>() { "dog", "bar", "bone" };

// Create a dictionary from the lists or have a dictionary from the beginning.
var dictKeywords = findList.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                           .ToDictionary(x => x.s, x => replaceList[x.i]);

string input = "the boy sold his car to buy a ball";
// Construct the regex pattern by joining the dictionary keys with an 'OR' operator.
string pattern = string.Join("|", dictKeywords.Keys.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)));

string output =
    Regex.Replace(input, pattern, delegate (Match m)
    {
        string replacement;
        if (dictKeywords.TryGetValue(m.Value, out replacement)) return replacement;
        return m.Value;
    });

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

### Output:

> the dog sold his bar to buy a bone

Comment: Like :) As a note, the anonymous type is not needed, the `Select`'s tuple is enough: var `dictKeywords = findList.Select((s, i) => (s, i)).ToDictionary(x => x.s, x => replaceList[x.i]);` (as a secondary note, this is not `O(n)`, but it's something to test)

Comment: What would the complexity be?

Comment: @Jimi Correct. But that would require C# 7.1 (many devs haven't upgraded yet). I also didn't use inline declaration for the `out` parameter for the same reason (requires C# 7.0, IIRC).

Comment: @Daniel Figuring out the exact time complexity for regex isn't easy (I must admit that I'm not very good at analyzing time complexity though). You'll have to do some tests. On a related note, you _might_ get better performance if you use `RegexOptions.Compiled` but again, it all comes down to testing both options _with real data_ because YMMV. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9969158/8967612) for more.

Comment: These are 4 implementations of the Aho–Corasick. [First](https://gist.github.com/alexandrnikitin/e4176d6b472b39155a7e0e5d68264e65), [Second](https://github.com/pdonald/aho-corasick) (both simple), [Third](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/aho%E2%80%93corasick-algorithm/) (probably won't do here) and [Fourth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AhoCorasick/) (a NuGet Package, recent). Getting this algorithm right means to adapt it to specifc requirements. It's not O(n), anyway (just the linear search pattern is).

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Regex, [`string.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) would suffice

```
var input = "the boy sold his car to buy a ball";
var oldvalues = new List<string>() { "boy", "car", "ball" };
var newValues = new List<string>() { "dog", "bar", "bone" };
var output = input;
for (int i = 0; i < oldvalues.Count; i++)
{
    output = output.Replace(oldvalues[i], newValues[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: I'm looking for something closer to O(n), where n is the size of the text, that's why I mentioned Aho-Corasick.